# How does Kunen's definitions of chains and antichains relate to more common definitions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I thought I understood chains and antichains in posets, but I'm a little lost with Kunen's definition in *Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs*. He says:

"2.2. DEFINITION. Let $\langle \mathbb{P},\leq \rangle$ be a partial order. A *chain* in $\mathbb{P}$ is a set $C \subset \mathbb{P}$ such that $\forall p,q \in C(p \leq q \cup q \leq p)$."

I'll pause here to note that I suspect the $\cup$ must be a misprint for $\lor$. First I'm having trouble seeing how the union symbol in this property can even be grammatical. The best I can come up with for interpreting it would be akin to saying $(p \leq q \land q \leq p)$ which seems entirely too restrictive to be a useful definition of a chain in anything like the sense it usually means. However, since the rest of the definition loses me, I suspect my confusion stems from this. Anyway, it continues:

"$p$ and $q$ are *compatible* iff
$$
\exists r \in \mathbb{P} (r \leq p \land r \leq q);
$$
they are *incompatible* $(p \perp q)$ iff $\lnot \exists r \in \mathbb{P} (r \leq p \land r \leq q)$. An *antichain* in $\mathbb{P}$ is a subset $A \subset \mathbb{P}$ such that $\forall p,q \in A (p \neq q \implies p \perp q)$."

I'm confused about why the defintion of antichain seems to be dependent on minimal or even minimum elements. For example, take the set $\mathcal{P} \{ a,b,c \}$ with $\leq$ defined as the usual subset relation. An example of an antichain would be the set $\{ \{ a,b \} , \{ c \} \}$, at least by my usual understanding. But since I can find an $r$ that is $\leq$ both $\{ a,b \}$ and $\{ c \}$, namely $\emptyset$, wouldn't they be compatible by Kunen's definition, and thus not part of an antichain?  How could any set with a minimum element ever have antichains?

Comment: The antichain issue isn't just Kunen - throughout forcing, "antichain" is used in the incompatibility as opposed to incomparability sense. This is because it's incompatibilities which are genuinely important. This overloading of terminology is obnoxious in my opinion, but it's not specific to Kunen.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, I tend to agree that’s a little obnoxious. Mostly, in an introduction like this, I would have appreciated an explicit note that the definition differs in a key way, instead of having to infer it. Oh well!

Comment: This typo is actually rather common, due to its connection with the set theory statement $x \in U \cup V \iff (x \in U) \vee (x \in V)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\cup$ is a misprint for $\lor$. This is not the usual notion of antichain in a partial order, but it is the one needed for Martin’s axiom and forcing.

In $\wp(\{a,b,c\})$ no two elements are incompatible, because $\varnothing\le X$ for all $X\subseteq\{a,b,c\}$. The more useful example is $\wp(S)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ for an arbitrary set $S$, as in Ken’s second example: then incompatible sets are precisely disjoint sets, and antichains are precisely pairwise disjoint families.

Comment: I can’t tell you how relieved I am to confirm that misprint. I’m afraid to admit how long I spent trying to reconcile my understanding of union with this definition. On the rest, it hadn’t even occurred to me that I might be understanding the antichain definition fine, and that it was just a more restrictive definition than I was used to. Thank you!

Comment: @PatMuchmore: You’re welcome!